# DataTables pre-select filter option to show specific data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have searched high and low on how to set the default option of a dataTable column filter but I cannot find out how to do it. I am still a novice with DT's so I figured I would hit SO first and then tear into hours of documentation if nothing presents itself.

In any case, I have a function set up to to instantiate a new DT. It then adds a column filter to the "username" column in my table. The data all shows fine in the table. Success!!

In my column filter I have several usernames that appear as options. My question: how to I preselect one of the options and only make that users data show up in the table.

Scenario: In my users column I have the value of "Peter Pan". In my users column filter I have the option "Peter Pan". I am passing the value of "Peter Pan" into the page. How to I only show the value of Peter Pan in the table?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#userListTable').DataTable( {
            initComplete: function () {
                var api = this.api();
                api.columns().indexes().flatten().each( function ( i ) {
                    var column = api.column( 2 );
                    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                            .appendTo(
                                    $(column.header()).empty()
                            ).on( 'change', function () {
                                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex( $(this).val() );
                                column.search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false ).draw();
                            });
                    column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                    } );
                    select.val("Peter Pan");
                    select.trigger('change');
                } );
            }
        } );
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a sample fiddle ?

Comment: Assuming the filter code you have works, just trigger the change event on the right select

Comment: Ive never done a fiddle, I will have to look at how to do that and get back with you.

Comment: I added code to post above. Based upon your suggestion I am setting Peter Pan with select.val("Peter Pan"); and it works great. The only issue is the table does not update. Any thoughts?

Comment: Figured it out. Code has been added above.